# JavaScript Get Table Without First Column

Tags: javascript

I'm using a JavaScript function that I found on SO to export an HTML table to Excel. It works pretty well but I would like to exclude the first column of the HTML table when exporting to Excel. I can do this easily in jQuery but the function is in JS and I'm having trouble getting this to work. Can anyone suggest how I would modify this line of code to ignore the first column?

```
var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
```

where `table = document.getElementById("exporttable")`

EDIT - full code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()

</script>

<input id="exporttoexcel" name="ExportToExcel" type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('exporttable', 'Tab Name')" value="Export to Excel">
```

Comment: Please post the js code that does the operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var ctx = {
    worksheet:name || "Worksheet",
    table: table.innerHTML.replace(/<tr>\s*<td>[\s\S]*?<\/td>/ig,"<tr>")
};
```

However, understand that the output of `innerHTML` may be very different from the original source, and may be converted or adapted by the browser in the rendering process. Also, parsing HTML with regex is generally a bad idea, but in well-defined cases it can work effectively.

Comment: This did not work, thank you though. The output was the same as the original table.